# Automating password changes

Tags: password, replication

I'm trying to automate password changes on 36+ servers b/c doing it the manual way to ridiculous and annoying. Basically, I can run a 'grep -ir password' on 1 of my host linux servers and see how many servers respond to the query. I can then go to each one of them and cd into the proper directories and locations and run an update as ':1+$s1password+newpassword+g ' and then save the update. However, this is very tedious and I have to multiple it by how many directories responded to the query and then times that by 36+ servers.

So, can someone please assist if you know how to accomplish my inquire? The only thing I can think of but I don't know if it's right would be to do something like this...
grep -ir password | vi *directory/file | :1+$s1password+newpassword+g && :wq
OR MAYBE, I should be thinking of this as a bash script that needs to be created

Again, your solutions will be much appreciated, thank you!

Regards,

CG

Comment: Have you tried "passwd -e -n 60 -x 90 -w 10 <userid>" for example?  See "man passwd" - it sets the fields in the /etc/shadow file. Try it out on your account. And you should probably setup PAM to enforce strong passwords.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple commands already written to run a command on multiple machines. Investing a small amount of time to get this set up will pay you dividends. Some of the better known ones are [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/), [chef](https://www.chef.io/), [terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) and [puppet](https://puppet.com/).

With these you could deploy a simple script to say /root/pwupdate containing

```
#!/bin/sh
sed -i 's/old_encrypted_password/new_encrypted_password/' "$@"
```

mark it executable, and then tell ansible et al to run

```
EDITOR=/root/pwupdate vipw
```

Another, more interactive approach would be to use a command line [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) to open up terminals to each of the machines (typically using ssh) and then tell it to run the same command on all the terminals at the same time. I think that this approach is fine for 5 machines, but pushing it for 10 and probably unwieldy for 36. It does however have the advantage that you don't need to set anything up over the stuff I expect you already have.